# QT4/5 Creator cannot find -lGL

Tags: compiling, c++, qt-creator, ubuntu-sdk, ld

I installed the ubuntu mobile SDK a while ago on my ubuntu 13.04 machine via http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/

After a few days there appeared a compiler/linker error - even when compiling the standard GUI project for QT:

```
cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

A non QT c++ hello world project compiles and pretends to start (it says in the ide starting) but it never says "Hello World" or even quits.

Also the QT-Creator suddenly had a weird bug. When I clicked on "Develop" a few non-closeable windows appeared showing like a screenshot of the qt creator window.

I could not find out what happened, so I decided to uninstall the SDK and return to the standard software center QT Creator version. I used `ppa-purge` on the SDK ppa's and so I uninstalled the sdk ... I hope. But I still get the same errors. Only that weird bug disappeared.

I also tried apt-get purge on the QT creator but it did not seem to work (no settings were lost after reinstalling).

I thought maybe I should try installing the SDK again, but I heard it's complicated when I mix up QT4 and QT5 stuff. So I decided to ask for an answer here.

So, my question is, how can I get QT Creator working again? I don't really care whether I use QT4 or QT5. I did not write that much so this is no problem. I'd prefer QT5, though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev